# Who is the member of FINRA, SIPC?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have read a sentence in a material:

> TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc. is the contracted custodian and clearing firm of TD  Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd. for U.S. securities markets and is a member of  FINRA, SIPC.

Who is the member of FINRA, SIPC?
TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc. is a member of  FINRA, SIPC,or TD  Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd is a member of  FINRA, SIPC ?

Comment: If TD Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd were the member of FINRA, the sentence would read "...TD Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd, **which is** a member of..."

Comment: I'm confused by your bounty request. You are asking for a reputable source in a question about the parsing of a specific sentence? source for what?

Comment: is/is points to a parallel structure  or parse. The only reputable source for this is parallel structure explanations from language websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your sentence by replacing the complicated names with letters:

> ***X*** <sup>*[TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc.]*</sup> is the contracted custodian and clearing firm of ***Y*** <sup>*[TD Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd. for U.S. securities markets]*</sup> and is a member of ***Z*** <sup>*[FINRA, SIPC]*</sup>.

i.e.

> X ***is*** the contracted custodian and clearing firm of Y ***(1)*** and ***is*** a member of Z ***(2)***.

This is a sentence formed of two independent clauses ***sharing the same subject***. Clause (1) is connected to clause (2) by the coordinating conjunction ***and***. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar)) explains about the omissibility of the subject in such cases:

> ***One criterion for identifying a subject*** in various languages ***is the possibility of its omission in coordinated sentences*** such as the following:
>
> - The man hit the woman and [the man] came here.

So the fact the subject ***X*** was omitted in the clause (2) is the criterion which proves that X is the subject of clause (2). Otherwise a different subject should have been expressed. Fulfilling the function of prepositional object within the predicate of clause (1), Y cannot possibly be the subject of (2), without it being replaced by a pronoun.

[TheEnglishbureau](https://www.theenglishbureau.com/blog/omitting-the-subject/) explains that

> There are certain situations where it’s perfectly fine in English to leave out the subject. Whenever you use a sentence where the subject or ***the subject*** with an auxiliary is repeated then this ***can be left out after the conjunctions***: *and*, *but*, *or* and *then*.
>
> - I went into the kitchen and [I] made a cup of tea.

[Guinlist](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/) calls it *ellipsis*:

> The rule for ***ellipsis*** with these two conjunction types is that ***when two verbs have the same subject, coordinating conjunctions allow the second subject mention to be omitted*** but subordinating ones do not.
>
> - Water evaporates and … forms clouds.

So without omitting the subject in (2) your sentence would be:

> X is the contracted custodian and clearing firm of Y ***(1)*** and X is a member of Z ***(2)***.

Answer (score 2):

It says "TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc ... is a member".

It is easy to check these things https://brokercheck.finra.org/

Comment: Maybe stangledon is right.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinate elements must be parallel.

The second element here is a complete predicate: "is a member of FINRA, SIPC".   The first element must therefore also be a complete predicate: " is the contracted custodian and clearing firm of TD Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd. for U.S. securities markets".   The coordination then takes "TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc." as its subject.

There is no other predicate available in the sentence.   The only two finite verbs are the two instances of "is".

The name "TD Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd." is buried inside a prepositional phrase which is inside this first predicate.   It's an object.   It isn't available as a subject for the other predicate in the coordination that happens to contain it.

Comment: Might be helpful if you pointed out where the prepositional phrase is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parallel structure in the sentence, which is given by how the verb be is used twice followed by a noun phrase. It is a compound sentence.

- /TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc. **is** the contracted custodian and clearing firm of TD Ameritrade Hong Kong Ltd. for U.S. securities markets/ and /[**it**] **is** a member of FINRA, SIPC./

Ergo: TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc. is the subject of "is a member of FINRA, SIPC.

[parallel sentence structure](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/parallel_structure.html) That websites provides numerous examples of parallelism.

This is exactly like:

- The house **is** very expensive and **is** very beautiful.
- The lady **is** sitting on the lawn and **is** eating a sandwich.

There is no need to repeat the subject if the subject is the same for both predicates.

Subject pronouns - Repeat it or not
2/3/20200 Comments

> Generally, if you use the same subject pronoun in a compound sentence,
> you don’t need to mention it again unless the subject pronoun or the
> tense change.

[repetition of a subject](https://www.juicyenglish.com/blog/subject-pronouns-repeat-it-or-not)

One subject, two (noun) predicates with the verb "is",  linked by and "and."

[That makes **two reputable sources**.]